# Can I populate a Sharepoint calendar with an Outlook shared calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, calendar, sharepoint

I haven't been able to figure out how to populate the Sharepoint calendar with the shared calendar from the Outlook 2007 accounts connected to Sharepoint.  Is this possible, or does the Sharepoint calendar have to be separate?

Answer (score 1):

You can always add an overlay on the existing sharepoint calendar:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/work-with-multiple-exchange-and-sharepoint-calendars-in-one-sharepoint-calendar-HA101777171.aspx

Maybe this is a solution

Answer (score 0):

I found this: http://www.dlocc.com/articles/import-outlook-calendar-to-sharepoint/comment-page-1/#comment-2569

I have to admit though, I didn't get it to work. If I add an event in Outlook it doesn't get added to the SharePoint calendar. Some comments in the blog say it works though, give it a try. If you figure it out, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your article.

Unfortunately, that requires the user to go and copy all the appts periodically and bring them into Sharepoint.  I'm hoping for a way to have it automatically update.  Like you said, it won't keep updating added events.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like we're having the same problem, heh.